# Accidentally renamed a file in centos 5 in /lib folder, no idea what it was called, how to find out?

Tags: linux, centos-5

[image]

In the above image it I renamed the file accidentally to `l` and I have no idea what it was in the first place.  It's sorted by name, and I am 99% sure it started with an L, most likely lib....

And FYI: Undo was not available for this action.

Here's some code as requested:

```
[root@server ~]# file /usr/bin/* | grep "32-bit"
/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders-32:     ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
/usr/bin/gtk-query-immodules-2.0-32:      ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
/usr/bin/mbchk:                           ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, statically linked, stripped
/usr/bin/pango-querymodules-32:           ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

3:55pm Update:

```
[root@server ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i lsb
redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5
redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5


[root@server ~]# rpm -ql redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5 | grep "/lib"
/lib/ld-lsb.so.3
/lib/lsb
/lib/lsb/init-functions
/usr/lib/lsb
/usr/lib/lsb/install_initd
/usr/lib/lsb/remove_initd
/lib/lsb
/lib/lsb/init-functions
/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
/usr/lib/lsb
/usr/lib/lsb/install_initd
/usr/lib/lsb/remove_initd
```

How can I find out what the folder name used to be?

Comment: Did you do it through a terminal? If so, have you tried checking the `history` command to see what you did `mv x l`?

Comment: @nerdwaller unfortunate no, it was through the GUI with SSH Secure Shell, the same one shown in that img.

Comment: OK, you can run `mbchk -v`. If it works it will tell you its version. So let's hope it will *not* work :-)

Comment: `[root@server ~]# mbchk -v
mbchk (GNU GRUB 0.97)`  Another buddy asked to run this command, take a look: `[root@server ~]# diff /lib/ld-2.5.so /lib/l
[root@server ~]# ` (nothing happened with that one)

Comment: Nothing should happen. We already know it is a symlink, so the files are identical. Unfortunately I checked and removing the link does *not* disable 32-bit executables as I thought, so my test doesn't work. Devising another.

Comment: @lserni thank you.  I will be back in 15 minutes unfortunately i have a quick call for my day-job =).  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @lserni ok I think the answer is that the file name should be: `ld-lsb.so.3` - do you think that's correct?

Comment: Yes, I concur. Sorry for the delay, I had to grab some calories :-)

Comment: @lserni if this is wrong, what will I notice go wrong? haha...

Comment: I'd have said problems like this - http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=24905 - but possibly only after a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a symbolic link, and probably to `ld-2.5.so` (note the same date and file size as `ld-linux`).

If you can get hold of a CentOS somewhere, just run `ls -la /lib | grep ld-2.5` and you will find some links, among which the one you are missing.

Not having a CentOS 5 available I can't say for sure, but possibly `ld-lsb.so.2` or `ld-lsb.so.3`.

So first let's make sure you *do* have the lsb package installed.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i lsb
```

or
    $ sudo yum list installed | grep -i lsb

You should have something like "redhat-lsb" (or "something-lsb") in there. If you do, then list its contents and see what files does it have in "/lib".

```
$ rpm -ql nameofpackage | grep "/lib"
```

or
    $ repoquery --list nameofpackage

One of those should be /lib/ld-lsb-something. (If `repoquery` does not work, you need to install `yum-utils`: `sudo yum install yum-utils` first).

Comment: Just had a nice guy tell me  to do `ls -ls` on the file `lib/l` and it reports: `0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 17 00:12 lib/l -> ld-linux.so.2` that means that's the right name?

Comment: No, that means that it *is* a symbolic link to the file I suspected, but it still doesn't say what the original file name *was* (which is the point of a symlink). But I've been searching and apparently CentOS has `ld-lsb.so.2` support, so you *should* have a file reporting that size and date and called `ld-lsb.so.2`. From the file name ordered list, you don't. So it's almost sure that is the name you need.

Comment: I think you're right, does this help?  `[root@server ~]# rpm -qil glibc | grep ld-
/lib64/ld-2.5.so
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/ld-2.5.so
/lib/ld-linux.so.2`  and `[root@server ~]# ls -la /lib | grep ld-2.5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  130860 Jan  8 08:33 ld-2.5.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       9 Jan 17 00:08 ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.5.so`

Comment: Unfortunately no, the loader (if it's the loader) is installed by the LSB package and not by the glibc one. But I hacked together a test to check if my guess is correct.

Comment: Ok see above back to the question, which one should I use? I don't know what any of those do unfortunately

Comment: Take a look at the updated question with code output.

Comment: OK, then do a `rpm -qf ld-linux.so.2`, this will tell you to what package that file (and presumably the link, as this is a "library") belongs. Given that, do a `yum reinstall <packagename>`. Afterwards, you can delete your spurious `l`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be painful but try this. It should tell you about all files modified/missing from their original install (including config files).

```
rpm -qa --verify | grep missing
```

Hopefully you only have one lib file missing.

Comment: Why painful, just because it takes a while?